# Delphi - List Index Out Of Bounds(4)

Tags: delphi, runtime-error

I know this question has been brought up a million times, however, I cant understand why this code is throwing the error, I have tracked down the culprit FOR loop causing the error, however, I don't see anything wrong with it.

I'm getting the error - "List Index Out Of Bounds(4)"

```
function TNetwork.FeedForward(InputVals : array of Real) : Real;
var
  I : Integer;
begin

  for I := 0 to Length(InputVals)-1 do
  begin
    Input[I].Input(InputVals[I]);
  end;

  for I := 0 to Length(Hidden)-1 do
  begin
    Hidden[I].CalcOutput;
  end;

  Output.CalcOutput;

  Result := Output.GetOutput;
  end;
```

The error occurs on the second For Loop, here is where I set the size of the hidden array.

```
constructor TNetwork.Create(Inputs, HiddenTotal : Integer);
var
  C : TConnection;
  I, J : Integer;
begin
  LEARNING_CONSTANT := 0.5;

  SetLength(Input,Inputs+1);
  SetLength(Hidden,HiddenTotal+1);
```

So, as I see it, the loop executes only three times, so why is it trying to index the 4th space? never mind why, more importantly, HOW?

If someone could shed some light on the cause, and a possible fix, I would be ever grateful

For completion's sake, here is the complete unit..

```
unit NeuralNetwork_u;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls, ComCtrls, Math;

type
  TConnection = Class;
  TNeuron = class(TObject)
  protected
    Output : Real;
    Connections : TList;
    isBias : Boolean;
  public
    Constructor Create; overload;
    Constructor Create(BiasValue : Integer); overload;
    procedure CalcOutput;
    procedure AddConnection( Con : TConnection );
    function GetOutput : Real;
    Function F( X : Real ) : Real;
  end;

  TConnection = class
  private
    nFrom, nTo : TNeuron;
    Weight : Real;
  public
    constructor Create(a , b : TNeuron) ; overload;
    constructor Create(a, b : TNeuron ; W : Real) ; overload;
    function GetFrom : TNeuron;
    function GetTo : TNeuron;
    function GetWeight : Real;
    procedure AdjustWeight(DeltaWeight : Real);
  end;


type TInputNeuron = class(TNeuron)
public
  procedure Input (D : Real);
end;

type THiddenNeuron = class(TNeuron)
private
public
end;

type TOutputNeuron = Class(TNeuron)
private
public
end;

type TNetwork = class(TObject)
private
  LEARNING_CONSTANT : Real;
public
  Input : array of TInputNeuron;
  Hidden : array of THiddenNeuron;
  Output : TOutputNeuron;

  constructor Create(Inputs,HiddenTotal : Integer);
  function FeedForward(InputVals : array of Real) : Real;
  function Train(Inputs : array of Real ; Answer : Real) : Real;
  function TrainOnFile(Epochs : Integer ; TrainingFile : String) : Real;
end;

implementation

constructor TNeuron.Create;
begin
  Output := 0;
  Connections := TList.Create;
  isBias := False;
end;

Constructor TNeuron.Create(BiasValue : Integer);
begin
  Output := BiasValue;
  Connections := TList.Create;
  isBias := True;
end;

procedure TNeuron.CalcOutput;
var
  Sum : Real;
  Bias : Real;
  C : TConnection ;
  NeuronFrom, NeuronTo : TNeuron;
  I : Integer;
begin
  if isBias then

  else
  begin
    Sum := 0;
    Bias := 0;
    for I := 0 to Connections.Count do
    begin
      C := Connections[I];
      NeuronFrom := C.GetFrom;
      NeuronTo := C.GetTo;
      if NeuronTo = self then
      begin
        if NeuronFrom.isBias then
        begin
          Bias := NeuronFrom.GetOutput * C.GetWeight;
        end
        else
        begin
          Sum := Sum + NeuronFrom.GetOutput * C.GetWeight;
        end;
      end;
    end;
    Output := F(Bias + Sum);
  end;  
end;

procedure TNeuron.AddConnection(Con : TConnection);
begin
  Connections.Add(Con) ;
end;

function TNeuron.GetOutput : Real;
begin
  Result := Output;
end;

function TNeuron.F( X : Real ) : Real;
begin
  Result := 1.0 /(1.0 + Exp(-X));
end;

procedure TInputNeuron.Input ( D : Real);
begin
  Output := D;
end;

constructor TConnection.Create(a, b : TNeuron);
begin
  nFrom := a;
  nTo := b;
  Weight := Random * 2 - 1;
end;

constructor TConnection.Create(a, b : TNeuron ; w : Real);
begin
  nFrom := a;
  nTo := b;
  Weight := w;
end;

function TConnection.GetFrom : TNeuron;
begin
  Result := nFrom;
end;

function TConnection.GetTo : TNeuron;
begin
  Result := nTo;
end;

function TConnection.GetWeight;
begin
  Result := Weight;
end;

procedure Tconnection.AdjustWeight(DeltaWeight : Real);
begin
  Weight := Weight + DeltaWeight;
end;

constructor TNetwork.Create(Inputs, HiddenTotal : Integer);
var
  C : TConnection;
  I, J : Integer;
begin
  LEARNING_CONSTANT := 0.5;

  SetLength(Input,Inputs+1);
  SetLength(Hidden,HiddenTotal+1);

  for I := 0 to Length(Input)-1 do
  begin
    Input[I] := TInputNeuron.Create;
  end;

  for I := 0 to Length(Hidden)-1 do
  begin
    Hidden[I] := THiddenNeuron.Create;
  end;

  Input[Length(Input)-1] := TInputNeuron.Create(1);
  Hidden[Length(Hidden)-1] := THiddenNeuron.Create(1);

  Output := TOutputNeuron.Create;

  for I := 0 to Length(Input)-1 do
  begin
    for J := 0 to Length(Hidden)-1 do
    begin
      C := TConnection.Create(Input[I],Hidden[J]);
      Input[I].AddConnection(C);
      Hidden[J].AddConnection(C);
    end;  
  end;

  for I := 0 to Length(Hidden)-1 do
  begin
    C := TConnection.Create(Hidden[I],Output);
    Hidden[I].AddConnection(C);
    Output.AddConnection(C);
  end;  
end;

function TNetwork.FeedForward(InputVals : array of Real) : Real;
var
  I : Integer;
begin
  for I := 0 to Length(InputVals)-1 do
  begin
    Input[I].Input(InputVals[I]);
  end;

  for I := 0 to Length(Hidden)-1 do
  begin
    Hidden[I].CalcOutput;
  end;

  Output.CalcOutput;

  Result := Output.GetOutput;
end;

function TNetwork.Train(Inputs : array of Real ; Answer : Real) : Real;
var
  rResult : Real;
  deltaOutput, rOutput, deltaWeight, Sum, deltaHidden : Real;
  Connections : TList;
  C : TConnection;
  Neuron : TNeuron;
  I, J : Integer;
begin
  rResult := FeedForward(Inputs);
  deltaOutput := rResult * (1 - rResult) * (Answer - rResult);
  Connections := Output.Connections;
  for I := 0 to Connections.Count do
  begin
    C := Connections[I];
    Neuron := C.GetFrom;
    rOutput := Neuron.Output;
    deltaWeight := rOutput * deltaOutput;
    C.AdjustWeight(LEARNING_CONSTANT * deltaWeight);
  end;

  for I := 0 to Length(Hidden) do
  begin
    Connections := Hidden[I].Connections;
    Sum := 0;
    for J := 0 to Connections.Count do
    begin
      C := Connections[J];
      if c.GetFrom = Hidden[I] then
      begin
        Sum := Sum + (C.GetWeight * deltaOutput);
      end;
    end;

    for J := 0 to Connections.Count do
    begin
      C := Connections[I];
      if C.GetTo = Hidden[I] then
      begin
        rOutput := Hidden[I].GetOutput;
        deltaHidden := rOutput * ( 1 - rOutput);
        deltaHidden := deltaHidden * Sum;
        Neuron := C.GetFrom;
        deltaWeight := Neuron.GetOutput * deltaHidden;
        C.AdjustWeight(LEARNING_CONSTANT * deltaWeight);
      end;
    end;
  end;
  Result := rResult;
end;

function TNetwork.TrainOnFile(Epochs : Integer ; TrainingFile : string) : Real;
var
  FileT : TStringList;
  Inputss : array of Real;
  Outputss : Real;
  I, C : Integer;
  sTemp : String;
  NumInputs, NumOutputs : Integer;
begin
  // Load File
  FileT := TStringList.Create;
  try
    FileT.LoadFromFile(TrainingFile);
  except
    raise Exception.Create('Training File Does Not Exist');
  end;

  for I := 0 to FileT.Count-1 do
  begin
    sTemp := FileT[I];
    if I = 0 then
    begin
      // get Configurators
      Delete(sTemp,1,Pos(' ',stemp));   // no Longer need training Set count
      NumInputs := StrToInt(Copy(sTemp,1,Pos(' ',sTemp)-1));
      Delete(sTemp,1,Pos(' ',sTemp));
      NumOutputs := StrToInt(Copy(sTemp,1,Length(sTemp)));
      SetLength(Inputss,NumInputs+1);
    end
    else
    begin
      for C := 0 to NumInputs-1 do
      begin
        Inputss[C] := StrToFloat(Copy(sTemp,1,Pos(' ',sTemp)-1));
        Delete(sTemp,1,Pos(' ',sTemp));
      end;
      Outputss := StrToFloat(Copy(sTemp,1,Length(sTemp)));

      Train(Inputss,Outputss);
    end;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: Much better q than your last one.  In your second loop, assign Hidden[I] to a local variable of the same type, then, on a new line, call CalcOutput on the local var.  That will tell you whether it's the array reference Hidden[I] which is causing the exception or the call to CalcOutput.  From a v. quick look, I'm guessing your "for I := 0 to Connections.Count" should say "Connections.Count - 1" and that may be the source of your problem..

Comment: If the failing loop is accessing the 4th index, then it is iterating 5 times, not 3 times. Also, I see no possible way for the *second* loop to fail with this error, but I can see how the *first* loop could if you are not careful - think of what happens if `Length(InputVals)` is greater than `Length(Input)`. Also, `TNetwork.Create()` has some memory leaks when populating the `Input` and `Hidden` arrays. You are assigning 2 objects to `Input[Length(Input)-1]` (leaking one of them) and 2 objects to `Hidden[Length(Hidden)-1]`. And who is responsible for freeing the `TConnection` objects?

Comment: @MartynA Thanks, ill try your suggestion, and report back asap

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for pointing out those issues, ill fix them up asap, as for the Inputvals being greater than Input, yes it could happen, but as this is just a means that i will use to make a program, so i would know to not make such an error (lazy i know, but im aiming for functionality first), Ill be sure to patch those leaks , but at the moment im really just wanting to be able to compile this and test it, unless of course these issues you pointed out are related to the original issue? (Still, thanks)

Comment: In `TNetwork.Train()`, all of your loops are going out of bounds, you are not subtracting `-1` from any of the counts.  You should consider using `for I := Low(arr) to High(arr)` instead of `for I := 0 to Length(arr)-1` when looping through dynamic arrays, that would be safer and cleaner.

Comment: "so i would know to not make such an error (lazy i know"  Yes, but if you get in the habit of getting these minor details right first time, I think you'll be pleasantly surprised how often code works first time.

Comment: True lol, ill work on that... thanks for the suggestion Remy, ill reprogram all the for loops to use your method! Its always been bugging me to do Length() on an array

Comment: To the Close-voter:  On what objective basis does this q deserve to be closed?

Comment: @MartynA It appears to be a simple typographical error, something which isn't likely to be useful to future readers. The actual issue was hidden in a "wall of code" outside of where OP *thought* the error was. At least the problematic code was included, just not narrowed down.

Comment: @JerryDodge:  Maybe, but there may be value anyway in showing how the problem was diagnosed.  Plus, IIRC, last time the OP was castigated for not posting enough code, so going from one extreme to the other is to be expected a bit.

Comment: @MartynA I'm unaware of OP's prior question - each question should be self-contained, and if based on another question, should link it. At least I didn't downvote it.

Comment: @Martyn Cutting down the code is always a good move though. For everyone, especially the asker.

Comment: Should I reduce the code to only the problem area we identified?

Comment: If you had narrowed down your code to the actual problematic area to be posted in your question, chances are you yourself would have caught your error before even posting this question. Instead the community sifted through your code to find it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  Sure, I'm not arguing.  It just dismays me a bit the reception some obviously keen-to-learn posters get here compared with the JohnGolfOils of this world, and the way the "rules" here are prayed in aid.

Comment: Jerry, I was unaware that the problem was in a totally different spot than what I thought, I'm quite happy I posted the entirety of the code otherwise it would never have been pointed out, but I took note of what you said, I'll be sure to do this in the future!

Comment: I think you're lucky you posted your full code, because if you didn't, your question would have been severely downvoted and closed immediately.

Comment: Exactly why I'm not really too worried that I posted the code, however I do get that posting a wall of code is most of the time unnecessary, but in this case it helped to solve the error, the code is now compiling and running as it should, lol I'm quite extatic that my neural network has finally seen the light of day, I now understand the implementation part of neural networks too, it's not really hard once you "get" it

Comment: @Martyn Kazuto got a good reception. Critical advice for sure, but advice all the same. He took it, learnt from it, asked a much better question, and has benefited. Everything is working as it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for I := 0 to Connections.Count do
```

You run off the end of the list here. Valid indices are `0` to `Connections.Count-1` inclusive. You go one too far.

You make this mistake repeatedly. You need to fix it everywhere, of course.

The *list index out of bounds* error is generally seen when you perform an out of bounds access of a collection class like `TList` or `TStringList`.

On the other hand, array bounds errors are unpredictable unless you have enabled range checking. If you do that, and you should, then you get a runtime error for such events. You'll want to enable range checking.

Comment: My god... I kept looking at the wrong place for the error LOL.. Thanks @David , the error lied in the calcOutput function as you said, I also fixed all the invalid for loops

Comment: Strange thing is that i do have range checking enabled, it didn't catch the error...

Comment: @KazutoKirigaya Range checking doesn't check dynamic lists, as in your case. The compiler has no idea how many items might be in that list, and with a `for` statement, doesn't even know that it's supposed to have a `- 1` on it. A `for` statement might be iterating a 1-based array.

Comment: @Kazuto Yes, range checking acts on arrays. Collection classes perform their own checking, as you discovered.

Comment: Yeah I realized that, good to know these things, will surely help out in the future <3 thanks for all the help guys!

Answer (score 3):

This is a minor supplement, not alternative, to @David's answer.

Especially when dynamic arrays are involved, doing something like

```
  for I := 0 to Length(Hidden)-1 do
  begin
    Hidden[I].CalcOutput;
  end;
```

is a kind of premature optimisation, because if an exception occurs on the

```
    Hidden[I].CalcOutput;
```

line, it may not be easy for someone not fully au fait with Delphi's debugger, how to use it and what the exception message is actually referring to (which isn't always obvious) to tell whether the exception is arising on the indexing of the Hidden[] array, or the call to CalcOutput on its Ith item.  So, at least for debugging purposes, it can be useful to do something like this:

```
var
  H :  THiddenNeuron; 
[...]
  for I := 0 to Length(Hidden) -1 do
  begin
    H := Hidden[I];
    H.CalcOutput;
  end;
```

and then it becomes easy to distinguish the two possible places the original code might be going wrong.

Comment: I understand this concept and totally makes sense, hence I made these changes in my code where ever it was applicable, learning new things each day.... Thanks

Comment: Now David's the expert on this next topic, but wouldn't that make it heavier on heap allocations (thus affecting performance)? Or would it actually be completely opposite? Because I can imagine how calling ` Hidden[I].CalcOutput;` for each iteration of the loop might perform its own internal heap allocation each time, whereas declaring a single variable `H` would only be one. Which one is correct?

Comment: I actually asked a new question on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32107543/which-scenario-is-lighter-heavier-on-heap-allocations

Comment: @Martyn The debugger will show CalcOutput on the call stack surely. I would not create a local variable just for this. The code in the Q is cleaner.