# Which scenario is lighter/heavier on heap allocations?

Tags: delphi, loops, memory-management, heap-memory

As a follow-up to [a previous answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32107065/988445), I became curious of how heap allocations work in a loop.

Take the following two scenarios for example:

**Declaration:**

```
SomeList: TObjectList<TSomething>;
```

**Scenario 1:**

```
begin
  for X := 1 to 10 do
    SomeList[X].DoSomething;
end;
```

**Scenario 2:**

```
var
  S: TSomething;
begin
  for X:= 1 to 10 do begin
    S:= SomeList[X];
    S.DoSomething;
  end;
end;
```

Now what I'm curious about is how heap allocations work in either scenario. Scenario 1 is directly calling the list item in each loop iteration, which I'm wondering if it adds to the heap and releases for each time the loop iterates. The second scenario on the other hand, obviously has one heap allocation, by simply declaring a local variable.

What I'm wondering is which scenario performs the heavier load on heap allocation (as being one leading cause to performance issues)?

Comment: Neither of them allocates any memory, so neither is more efficient from a memory standpoint (other than allocation of a pointer variable in scenario 2, which is irrelevant, and which the compiler may well optimize away). The only difference is: which is easier for you to type and understand for maintenance?

Comment: The way I understand is that the fact that I have a local variable declared adds to the heap, along with the acquisition of the list item upon each loop iteration. That understanding is apparently wrong.

Comment: The local (object pointer) variable is not allocated on the heap at all. It's a local variable, allocating exactly `SizeOf(Pointer)` bytes of stack space (which I mentioned in my comment, and which I also mentioned the compiler may optimize away anyway). There is no memory allocation in your code that affects the heap. (Just FYI, I'm not the one that downvoted; I think the question was fine, although it is based on a total misunderstanding of how variables are allocated.)

Comment: @KenWhite Well thank you, that's exactly what I was trying to figure out.

Comment: To add... since pointers are treated one way... does that mean if I had a `string` variable that it *would* add to the heap?

Comment: @Jerry A string variable is a pointer. Allocate a local string variable and you allocate a pointer of the stack (or just in a register if the compiler can optimise there which perhaps it can't for a managed type). The content of the string is stored on the heap. The pointer points to the content.

Comment: In addition to @DavidHeffernan's comment, one can reference multiple times the same string and yet it will have only one heap object, a new one is only created when you modify the content of the second or whatever next different variable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Now what I'm curious about is how heap allocations work in either scenario.

There are no heap allocations in your example (unless `DoSomething()` is allocating memory internally).

> Scenario 1 is directly calling the list item in each loop iteration

So is Scenario 2.

> I'm wondering if it adds to the heap and releases for each time the loop iterates.

Nothing is being added to the heap.

> The second scenario on the other hand, obviously has one heap allocation, by simply declaring a local variable.

Local variables are allocated on the **stack**, not on the **heap**.  Variables can **point** at memory on the heap, though.  Your `S` variable in Scenario 2 does, because `TObject`-derived classes are always allocated on the heap.  `S` is just a local variable on the stack that points at the heap memory occupied by the `TSomething` object.

> What I'm wondering is which scenario performs the heavier load on heap allocation (as being one leading cause to performance issues)?

Neither, because there is no heap allocation in your example.